# Configure SqsListener as Long Pooling

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs

I am implementing a SQS subscriber using spring boot and after a few research on internet I have found the project `spring-cloud`.

Use the annotation `@SqsListener` looks pretty easy to receive messages from a topic but I would like to implement it as Long Pooling instead of short pooling that receives every message as soon it arrives.

```
    @SqsListener(
        value = ["queue"],
        deletionPolicy = SqsMessageDeletionPolicy.ON_SUCCESS
    )
    fun subscribeToSSmsg: String) {
    ....
    }
```

This is working smooth but I would like to receive messages using long pooling. Is there any way to do it using spring-cloud?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With AWS Java SDK 1.X.

You need to define a custom `org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.config.SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` bean which would need a `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSAsync` bean.

Add the below beans to your configuration.

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setWaitTimeOut(20); //Long polling, the maximum value of 20 seconds
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(10); //The maximum number of messages you want to read in a single poll
    return factory;
}

@Bean
@Primary
AmazonSQSAsync amazonSQSAsync(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
    return new AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient(
        AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withRegion("region") //Set an appropriate region
            .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
            .build());
}
```

Also ensure the HTTP clients you are using has a higher timeout than the value you set for the long polling.

Comment: How does it works? My method will receive a list of messages?

Comment: There is a single polling thread and multiple worker thread (Default 2 per number of @SqsListener annotation and you can provide this) which process the message. Each worker thread would receive 1 message at a time. If you want to dive deeper look at the source code for `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. Nothing changes where you add the SqsListener annotation and you write your function to handle a single message. All this coordination of polling and handing them to the worker and finally deleting your message on success is taken care for you.

Comment: thanks for explanation but I am missing something. I am running local tests using Localstack and when I publish a single message on queue, my function `subscribeToSSmsg()` is automatically called - it's being called for each message that arrives. I thought that I was going to receive 10 messages on 20 seconds - each 20 seconds, i could receive 10 messages. What I miss?

Comment: SQS is a pull based messaging system i.e. you need to poll on a constant interval. Long polling helps you reduce the number of polling requests. Let's say you don't have any messages on the queue, then it would wait for 20 seconds for a single polling request and would start polling again. If you do receive messages, then it would be accessed by the poller. Let's say your polling application is down for sometime or you are getting a lot of messages and your queue has a lot of messages (more than 10 e.g.), in this case you would get all the 10 messages in a single polling request.

Comment: does AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient works with Fifo queues?

Comment: The batches are ordered at the client side and by default the maximum batching period is 200ms. Did you face any issues with FIFO queue ordering?

Comment: No, I was wondering because I have read on docs that AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient doesn't support FIFO queues so I was imagining if I can do long polling on FIFO

Comment: You are right, if you have a FIFO queue, do not use AmazonSQSBufferedAsyncClient